# iOS smartcard interfacing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, linker, xcode4.3, smartcard-reader

I was trying to write a code to access a card reader. and i have included the framework in my   projects but can't solve the linking problem ? Do u have any comments on this pls ?

> "_OBJC_CLASS_$_EAAccessoryManager", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in iSmartSDK
>   "_EAAccessoryDidConnectNotification", referenced from:
>         -[iSmart init] in iSmartSDK
>         -[iSmart dealloc] in iSmartSDK
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_EASession", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in iSmartSDK

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks to me as though you aren't linking against the ExternalAccessory framework.

Comment: thanks a lot, ya I should have included the External Accessory framework into my project.

Comment: Make sure to mark my answer as correct if it solved your problem.